# Website not posting to Facebook: security & app id issues

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm a new WordPress designer.  My site runs Tesseract Theme and is built with Beaver Builder.

**PROBLEM:**  When I post my website (https://louiseclark.tech) on Facebook it removed my site after a couple minutes.  Now when I try to post my site it gives me this message--> *It looks like a link you're sharing might be unsafe. If you can, please remove this link: louiseclark.tech Note: The unsafe link might be on the page you’re linking to.*

**What I've done to try and resolve:**

1. When I ran my site through the Facebook debugger I got this message:
   *The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.*
2. I created an app id following this instructional video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V97h03H21y0
3. I pasted my app id into my Yoast SEO plugin under the Facebook category.
4. Check my Google Webmaster Tools Sitemap...all is verified and sitemap set.
5. SSL certificate is set - checked with my hosting company SiteGround.  When I asked them about this problem they didn't really feel that the security issues where from their side.
6. I've reported this problem to the black hole that is Facebook support.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: First of all, this does not _stop_ people from posting this URL, if they want to – then they have to complete the CAPTCHA first. And if you scroll down, you will see that at the bottom it says, _“If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.”_ with the last part being a link. _That_ is where you should report this.

Comment: I have reported it.  However, Facebook doesn't ever respond.  When I sent the report it stated that they don't necessarily respond to individual reports.  Basically, my issue reporting if for their benefit and not mine.  Or so it seems.  I also don't want people going to my website to hit a security tag.  Regardless of whether it's Facebook's mistake, it looks bad on me.  I guess I thought this was a programming problem on my end.  That I had somehow forgotten to add some sort of coding snippet that would register the site correctly with Facebook.

Comment: No, the Open Graph meta data has no influence on whether Facebook considers a site “safe” or not. // One possibility is that you triggered this yourself through intensive testing (posting the URL multiple times, maybe even removing the posts shortly afterwards again) - in that case, it will go away again by itself once enough other users have confirmed the CAPTCHA. Another possibility is that your site is hosted on a server that also hosts “bad” sites, or that your site landed on one of the major malware/spam blocklists.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone sees this thread, I found the solution.

When I moved my WordPress sites to managed WordPress hosting I also migrated my websites to https with the SSL certificates.  While the pages were migrated and displaying the https just fine, the images still held their old url (http).

I did two things:

1. I installed SSL Content Fixer plugin.  This worked for some images but not others.
2. I installed Better Search Replace plugin.  I had found the specific insecure images using Firefox.  From my page in Firefox, I went to:
   *Tools -> Page Info -> Media* This showed me every image/js/css call on this page. Finding these images allowed me to use the plugin to make the changes.

It worked.  I'm quite sure knowing how to code my site would be much better in this situation.  But I'm a newbie and this is what I could come up with.

**What I learned:**  It's a flag when you have a secure site that embeds non secure objects/images.